# Aggregation of Aggregation -> Elastic search query

Tags: elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-query

I have a use case where in I need to do aggregation query (histogram) on the data series to find out RPS and then calculate 95th percentile for the resulting series (RPS)

Use output of the aggregation and calculate 95th percentile for the same.

I have a series of data on which I am aggregating to calculate RPS

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
        "filter": [
            {
                "range": {
                    "@timestamp": {
                         "gte": "2023-04-05T02:40:00.000Z",
                         "lte": "2023-04-05T02:42:00.000Z"
                     }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "rps": {
      "date_histogram": {
          "field": "@timestamp",
          "fixed_interval": "1s"
       }
    }
  }
}
```

I would want to calculate 95th percentile for the result that I get out of this query, something like this

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
        "filter": [
            {
                "range": {
                    "@timestamp": {
                         "gte": "2023-04-05T02:40:00.000Z",
                         "lte": "2023-04-05T02:42:00.000Z"
                     }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "rps": {
      "date_histogram": {
          "field": "@timestamp",
          "fixed_interval": "1s"
       }
     },
     "aggs": {
             "percentiles": {
                 "field": "rps._count",
                 "percents": [95]
             }
     }
  }
}
```

Here the second aggregation gives a null value, as its not able to access first aggregation query's output, is something like this possible?